# Execute pending job with ActiveJob in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, actionmailer, rails-activejob

I have this code to test ActiveJob and ActionMailer with Rspec
I don't know how really execute all enqueued job

```
describe 'whatever' do
  include ActiveJob::TestHelper

  after do
    clear_enqueued_jobs
  end  

  it 'should email' do
    expect(enqueued_jobs.size).to eq(1)
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe this will help https://medium.com/@chuckjhardy/testing-rails-activejob-with-rspec-5c3de1a64b66

Answer (score 30):

The proper way to test will be to check number of enqueued jobs as in your example, and then test each job separately. If you want to do integration testing you can try perform_enqueued_jobs helper:

```
describe 'whatever' do
  include ActiveJob::TestHelper

  after do
    clear_enqueued_jobs
  end  

  it 'should email' do
    perform_enqueued_jobs do
      SomeClass.some_action
    end
  end
end
```

See [ActiveJob::TestHelper docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/TestHelper.html#method-i-clear_enqueued_jobs)

Comment: Can someone show a less contrived example of what this would look like with a mailer that accepts arguments? I can't seem to get this to work with something like `OrderMailer.receipt_email(order.id)`.

Comment: Make sure you tack on the deliver_now or deliver_later method when testing a mailer and trying to fire the job.

Answer (score 26):

Here is how I solved a similar problem:

```
# rails_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before :example, perform_enqueued: true do
    @old_perform_enqueued_jobs = ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_jobs
    @old_perform_enqueued_at_jobs = ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_at_jobs
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_jobs = true
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_at_jobs = true
  end

  config.after :example, perform_enqueued: true do
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_jobs = @old_perform_enqueued_jobs
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_at_jobs = @old_perform_enqueued_at_jobs
  end
end
```

Then in specs we can use:

```
it "should perform immediately", perform_enqueued: true do
  SomeJob.perform_later  
end
```

Comment: Great answer. I added this to a file in spec/support. Seems that this is 100% necessary for testing email values in integration tests.

Comment: Is this really the only way to ensure jobs are performed inline for specific integration tests? It blows my mind that there isn't a simpler way to do this.

Comment: @cgat No - you could place "ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_jobs = true" in a before block, and your enqueued jobs will have been performed in time for your examples.

Answer (score 1):

I have an `:inline_jobs` helper, where applied to a test it will perform the enqueued jobs and clear the enqueued jobs

```rb
module InlineJobHelpers
  def self.included(example_group)
    example_group.around(:each, :inline_jobs) do |example|
      perform_enqueued_jobs do
        example.run
      end
    ensure
      clear_enqueued_jobs
    end
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ActiveJob::TestHelper, :inline_jobs
  config.include InlineJobHelpers, :inline_jobs
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just combined all the best pieces, +included sidekiq:

***spec/support/perform_jobs.rb***:

```rb
require 'sidekiq/testing'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  Sidekiq::Testing.fake!

  config.around(:each, perform_jobs: true) do |example|
    Sidekiq::Testing.inline! do
      queue_adapter = ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter
      old_perform_enqueued_jobs = queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_jobs
      old_perform_enqueued_at_jobs = queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_at_jobs
      queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_jobs = true
      queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_at_jobs = true
      example.run
    ensure
      queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_jobs = old_perform_enqueued_jobs
      queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_at_jobs = old_perform_enqueued_at_jobs
    end
  end

end
```

***spec/some_spec.rb***:

```rb
it 'works', perform_jobs: true do
  ...
end
```